# SIFR Font tweaking a nightmare!

Tags: fonts, sifr

I've been trying to tweak my SIFR navigation. I'm replacing with Gill (although I've had the same issue with other fonts).

The problem is that no matter what I do with the letter spacing, short words are ok with one setting but not long words and vice versa.

In order to stop any words wrapping I have to set letter spacing to 1px (for example) but this then causes the larger words to have a much bigger movie than they need and as the nav is horizontal this pushes the next item too far over to the right.

Has anyone had the same issue? And if so, did you solve it?

See image here: http://www.glg-group.com/gill.jpg

It's driving me crazy!

Many thanks

Tom Gosling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use sIFR 3 you can add the `fitExactly: true` parameter for the replacements, this will make the Flash movies exactly wide enough to fit the text.

(With the caveat that Flash might use incorrect values, but you can use the `offsetLeft`/`offsetTop` and `tuneWidth`/`tuneHeight` parameters to tune the text position and movie dimensions.)

Comment: Thanks Mark, you're a star! fitExactly and tuneWidth did it in the end.

Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for not directly answering your question, but you may want to try [Cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon)

> Cufón aims to become a worthy
>   alternative to sIFR, which despite its
>   merits still remains painfully tricky
>   to set up and use.

Hope it deals with the issue.